# How do I get the Access-Token and Access-Token-Secret?

Tags: oauth, twitter

Can anyone explain me these terms with respect to OAuth ?

```
Consumer Key 
Consumer Secret
Access Token
Access Token Secret
```

Also, when I registered my application with twitter I got the *consumer key* and *consumer secret* but how do I get the *access token* and *access token secret* ?

[image]